# bot.send_media_group Telegram bot issue

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I get this erro when trying to send a video with thumbnil:
An error occurred: Can't parse inputmedia: media not found

I am using Python 3.11.6 and python-telegram-bot v 20.7

Here is the code:

```
video_input = InputFile(local_video_path) 
thumb_input = InputFile(thumbnail_path) if thumbnail_path else None
print(thumbnail_path)
media_video = InputMediaVideo(media=video_input, thumbnail=thumb_input)
print("Pass 1")
await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=group_chat_id, media=[media_video])
print("Pass 2")
```

I get the correct video path, thumbnil path and "Pass 1" printed

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: did you try to check `print( media_video )`?